# Javascript executor unable to scroll due to activities on page (Selenium automation)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is my script testing various scenarios with Javascript executor. However, it fails on the last step, which was to scroll. I noticed that after navigating to the page, the elements were taking an exceptionally long time to load. I tried several wait options but didn't work.

```
package UI;
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class JavascriptExecutor1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        // accept popup
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"accept-choices\"]"))).click();
        
        JavascriptExecutor jxect = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // Like API to javascript command library
        
        // This will print the title of the page.
        String script = "return document.title;"; // The script is title display as string
        String title = (String) jxect.executeScript(script); // Tells javascript to execute the script n save it in title variable
        System.out.println(title);  //Printing out whatever script we we executed that is saved in title variable.

        // We want to click the button
        
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
        jxect.executeScript("myFunction()");
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        
        //To highlight a button
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/button"));
        jxect.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='5px solid red'", button);
        
        //to scroll
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.w3schools.com/");
        WebElement getstarted = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[17]/div/a"));
        jxect.executeScript("argument[0].scrollintoview(true);", getstarted); 
            
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in method `scrollintoview` - it should be `scrollIntoView`.
And typo in `argument` variable - it should be `arguments`

Code below works for me:

```js
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/");
WebElement getStarted = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#getdiploma"));
jxect.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", getStarted);
```